# Sublime - search by class

Tags: sublimetext

How can I find some file in Sublime by class/ID name?

I need to support: css/scss/javascript/html/tag/jsp files?

Comment: Your question is about Sublime text, not about technologies mentioned in your tags.

Comment: you can search in entire project with `Ctrl + Shift + F` or in the menu: `Find > Find in Files...`

Answer (score 0):

Ctrl + F, then search for some class or whatever you want in opened docs, or entire site. I don't know if Sublime has "entire site search" but if not, you may install DreamWeaver or some other IDE that allows you to reach this lighting faster.

Cheers!